# Remove parent of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, parent-child, android-textinputlayout

I want to remove the container of my TextInputLayout on endDrawable click. I have multiple instances of these containers. I have 2 questions:

1. When I first initialise the `onClick()` method for each one in a for loop in `onCreate()`, do I have to use `getId()` to find the parent container of each TextInputLayout?
2. How can I use `removeView()`, `getParent()` (or otherwise) methods to remove the required view?

```
phoneNumberLayoutViews[v].setEndIconOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            // Remove parent layout

                        }
                    });
```

Small Edit: I had to call `getParent()` multiple times to remove the parent I wanted. First, only the drawable was removed, then the TextInputEditText (I think), then the TextInputLayout, then the container.

```
((ViewGroup) view.getParent().getParent()
                             .getParent()
                             .getParent()
                             .getParent())
                             .setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @barotia I have an "Add Contact" activity. The user can input multiple phone number-type pairs.  The layout initially only shows 1 entry, but the user can choose to add more using a button underneath which adds another phone number-type pair, up to 5 entries. The user should be able to add/delete these entries (added using the button I mentioned, deleted using a drawable at the end of each phone number EditText).

Comment: I think that it would be easier to create a custom view, with a custom drawable, than modifying the existing edittext. In that way, you will have full control over the drawables.

Comment: True, might attempt that in the near future. For now I'll do it the "dirtier" way..

Comment: But why? It is harder, it takes more time, it is harder to modify in the future.

Comment: I haven't attempted to create a custom view before, so I don't know how to go about it. I take it I need a class that combines the views I currently have, which are parent (LinearLayout) and children (TextInputEditText and AutoCompleteTextView). But I don't know how to override the TextInputEditText's drawable to remove the parent.